# Dropwizard, Jersey, unit testing - GET throws ConstraintViolationException: The request entity was empty at

Tags: junit, jersey, dropwizard

I have Dropwizard application and I am writing unit tests for it. I am following Dropwizard's documentation to do so : http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/testing.html

What I am missing is how can I add parameter to my test which invokes GET method? 
Here in the documentation :

assertThat(resources.client().resource("/person/blah").get(Person.class))
                .isEqualTo(person);

What if my get method has a parameter?

In Jersey's WebResource there are:

```
    @Override
    public <T> T get(Class<T> c) throws UniformInterfaceException, ClientHandlerException {
        return handle(c, build("GET"));
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T get(GenericType<T> gt) throws UniformInterfaceException, ClientHandlerException {
        return handle(gt, build("GET"));            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters are part of the resource URI. You can embed them in the string:

```
assertThat(resources.client().resource("/person/blah?a=b").get(Person.class)).isEqualTo(person);
```

Or you can build the URI dynamically:

```
URI resourceUri = UriBuilder.fromPath("/person/blah").queryParam("a", "b").build();
assertThat(resources.client().resource(resourceUri).get(Person.class)).isEqualTo(person);
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but that only works when the GET method being tested doesn't have a parameter. When it does, for example:    @GET
 @Path("/packages")
 public List<RPackage> getPackagesList(@SessionAuth User user) {
  try {
   return user.getWorker().getPackagesInfo(user.getSessionKey());    
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
   throw new StatAceRestException(e); 
  }
 }     I have: Test  c.s.j.s.c.ContainerResponse:419 [main] - The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: The request entity was empty

Comment: Method parameters such as those are injected by Dropwizard/Jersey. Presumably you're registering a corresponding provider in your Dropwizard application class; [you also need to register it in your test class](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/7ES9GPs2O2k).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work. Actually the problem described here was with dependencies :              SEVERE: Missing dependency mine is:                                              The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: The request entity was empty                                                            at io.dropwizard.jersey.jackson.JacksonMessageBodyProvider.validate(JacksonMessageBodyProvider.java:70)